# onsenui ons-switch click returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am using onsenui version 1.

Every time when i click the button i am getting checked as undefined…

```
<ons-list modifier="inset" class="settings-list">        
       <ons-list-item >
         <span class="trn" data-trn-key="enabled_push_notification">Restaurant ON/OFF</span>
         <ons-switch id="s"  modifier="list-item" onclick ="checking();"     ></ons-switch>
       </ons-list-item>
     </ons-list>
```

My javascript function

```
function checking(){
    alert("checking........+1"+document.getElementById("s").checked);
}
```

Comment: Maybe because there is no element with id "s" ? Try `input-id="s"`

Comment: @Smollet thanks for your quick reply then should we change something in javascript

Comment: @Smollet no its not working

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: i am getting error when i use input-id

Comment: paste.ofcode.org /MFk8GvQH2NqrbXZh5HYwF8

Comment: its is https and please remove space between org and / to see error

Comment: but no error when i us e id @Smollet777

Comment: https://codepen.io/smollet777/pen/YRBbzv code that you have provided seems to work in isolation in the snippet

Comment: [switch documentation](https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-switch.html#attributes)